# Log all commands executed regardless of shell?

Tags: security, logs, exec, tracing, ebpf

Suppose a user runs the following command:

```
zcat file.gz | grep something | gzip > grepped.gz
```

I'm looking for a kernel feature (a BPF filter perhaps?) that would note all of the `execve`s, chain together their stdins/stdouts and reconstruct that in a similar form, putting it into system logs. Is there a way to do that without interfacing with the shells?

Comment: You want to enable and configure `auditd`. Logs can be quite large and should be rotated regularly. You can pare down the rules to limit what gets logged.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using process-accounting

Package usually is named `psacct` or `acct`

Install needed packages

```bash
sudo apt install acct
```

Start daemon to automatically enable process accounting

```bash
sudo systemctl enable --now acct.service
```

To check last run commands execute `lastcomm`

#### Using auditd

Install auditd daemon

Enable it on boot

```bash
sudo systemctl enable auditd
```

Add following rule

```bash
sudo auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve -k search_comment
```

Now to view logged messages for all users

```bash
sudo ausearch -k search_comment
```

or searching by specific UID

```bash
sudo ausearch -k search_comment -ui 1000
```

Comment: Thanks! Isn't it going to keep them in an unstructured, strace-like kind of format, as opposed to storing entire commands?

Comment: Kenrel logs process accounting data in binary format with [this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acct.5.html) structure. Auditd logs in human-readable format [definitions of fields in log file](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-documentation/wiki#documentation)

Comment: That's not exactly my question. It's more about: can I easily reconstruct a complex pipeline (with stdin, stdout) based on that information, or is it too fine-grained?

Comment: It is possible to include the `pipe` syscall in the `-S` switch by using `-S execve,pipe` and correlating the timestamps of the relevant syscalls. While this method may not be simple approach, it's worth noting that users are not required to log all of their commands by changing environment values such as PS1 to point to **logger** or other tools that rely on LD_PRELOAD.